Movie about an Australian trucker with psychiatric problems
The Hero: an Australian trucker with mental problems whose wife has left him.
The Heroine: lives with her pregnant sister and brother-in-law, has had an affair with brother-in-law. The sister finds out and throws her out of the house.
The hero has forgotten to take his medications and his delirious mind thinks the heroine is his wife and kidnaps her. A bunch of stuff happens in between but at the end the heroine kills the hero's wife, the hero takes his medication and comes to his senses. The couple live happily ever after.
Can any one please tell me the name of this movie?

Anything else you remember about this like maybe what kind of a truck he drove a pick up or delivery or anything

@war_Hero Yes I remember quite a lot, just not the name of movie or any of the actors. He drove a delivery truck.

was it like in mid 80's 90's

@war_Hero I am not really sure but I think early 00's.

Seems you're after the Australian film Puppy from 2005:

[After getting kicked out by her sister and] attempting suicide, sultry but down-on-her-luck swindler Liz (Nadia Townsend) is rescued by lonely tow truck driver Aiden (Bernard Curry). But instead of rushing her to the hospital, Liz’s savior abducts her to his remote farmhouse, convinced that she is the wife who abandoned him years earlier.

Here's the trailer (Warning: NSFW):




Yup, this is it. Thnx a lot.
